# How do I add an object array to the Route Value when I submit a form?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC view with a bunch of inputs.  When I submit the form, I want to add an object array to the route values, in addition to passing the model.  Basically I have a child grid on the page that users can add/remove items.  I don't want to save the changes until they are ready to save the entire page.

I have seen elsewhere on Stack Overflow how to add a field to the routing by using a hidden field, but how would I do an array of objects?

My View:

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("SaveThis", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "myPage" }))
    {
        //bunch of fields
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this)" class="btn btn-default btn-block bg-MBRBlue" />
        </div>
    }
```

The javascript I currently have:

```js
    <script>
        function submitForm(e) {
            debugger;
            var dataSets = getGridData();
            //code to add dataSets to routing would go here??
            $("#myPage").submit();
        }

        // more javascript code...

    </script>
```

The Controller code I would pass this to:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveThis(MyViewModel viewModel, GridDataViewModel[] gridData)
    {
        //code to save model info here

        //code to create/update/delete grid stuff here
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way, but i solved this by using Editor Templates like below:

Class Models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<GridDataViewModel> GridDataViewModels { get; set; }
}

class GridDataViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel view:

```
   <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GridDataViewModels)

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Then you add a new directory inside your view directory called "EditorTemplates" and inside it you add a new view with the exactly name of your ViewModel list. In this example i put the name "GridDataViewModel.cshtml".

Inside view of editor templates you put:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.GridDataViewModel
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Value" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

When you post your list will be inside your MyViewModel param. You can explore more things, but i think that this will give you some ideas.

This is my first answer, forgive me if i committed some english mistakes or my answer is not in the best format.

Comment: No worries on the response, your English is probably better than mine.  :-)  I am hoping there is something I can do with form.append(), but all the examples I see out there are for a single field, not an array of objects.

Comment: Can't you add this array in your ViewModel? You can create a new view just for this form too e follow my answer above